# Frame by frame animation with memory problems

Tags: android, animation, graphics, frame, animationdrawable

I am trying an app with a viewpager. Each page contains a background image and two or three ImageView but its really source is an AnimationDrawable (frame by frame animation-list in XML). I try display bitmaps efficiently as I see here: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html and I reduced images from png32 to png8, but I am still having memory problems.

What can I do? Are there any library to do that more efficiently? OpenGL?

Help please. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling large heap support, by adding this to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application android:largeHeap="true">
```

Also, you can use the Bitmap.Config type RGB_565 instead of ARGB_8888.